# Writing to a closed file in C

Tags: c, file, io

In C, how can I detect that I have written to a closed file?

Here is a trivial example I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Check for a filename, which will be used to open an output file.
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Filename expected from command line.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Here, I purposely close the file and then try to write to it.
    fclose(file);
    int written = fprintf(file, "hello there, friend\n");

    // Now I check a few things to see if the write was successful.
    printf("ferror(file) = %i\n", ferror(file));
    printf("errno        = %i\n", errno);
    printf("written      = %i\n", written);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from running this program and providing an output file, which I have called `output.txt`, is this:

```
ferror(file) = 0
errno        = 0
written      = 20
```

The [cplusplus.com reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) for `fprintf` says this about its return value:

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.
>
> If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned.

I expected a negative number as a return value from `fprintf`, but instead I got `20`; next I expected a non-zero error indicator for the file, but it is `0`. This makes it seem as though the string was successfully written to `output.txt`, but the file is empty.

In a scenario like this, is it possible to detect whether I have tried writing data to a closed file?

Edit:

I am writing this code on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using gcc 7.4.0.

Comment: You should capture `errno` immediately and not wait till after other calls have occurred and likely mutated the value.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I switched the lines around so I print `errno` first, but I got the same result.

Comment: What operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for reminding me. Sorry I forgot to add that in my original post. I have updated it.

Comment: A far more useful error message would be given by `fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));` . Don't give a generic string (eg "file") when you have the path easily available.  Or, just do `perror(argv[1])`.  Easier to write, follows common conventions, and easily localizable (i18nable(?)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`errno` is not useful in the currently-posted code.

First, the value of `errno` is valid only immediately after a call that fails - if the call is documented to set `errno`.  `fprintf()` is not:

> [**7.21.6.1 The `fprintf`
>   function**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> 1
>
> ```
>       #include <stdio.h>
>       int fprintf(FILE * restrict stream,
>            const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Returns**
>
> 14 The fprintf function returns the number of characters transmitted,
>   or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

There's no mention of `errno` being set by `fprintf()`.  Per [**7.5 Errors** , paragraph 3 of the C 11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3):

> The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of `errno` in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library function. The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard.

Since `fprintf()` is not documented to set `errno`, it's value is not useful after a call to that function fails.

Note that this code should indicate an error by returning a negative value, and not `20`, as your posted output indicates it's doing:

```
// Here, I purposely close the file and then try to write to it.
fclose(file);
int written = fprintf(file, "hello there, friend\n");
```

I am completely unable to duplicate that problem, so this is only a partial answer to address the use of `errno`.

Comment: I just wrote the same code and compiled it on MacOS and got the expected result, that is, `fprintf` returned `-1` and `ferror` returned a non-zero value.